# Is there a program that will tell you what type of hard drive your computer supports and if there are free ports

Tags: windows-7

I don't feel like opening my computer today, but I want to find out what type of hard drives my computer supports (i.e. SATA, SD).  Also, are there any free ports on the controller to which I can connect a hard drive? Is there a program that I can run that will tell me this, similar to the [crucial memory scanner](http://crucial.com/systemscanner), but for hard drives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. Use [Cpuz](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cpuid&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpuid.com%2F&ei=QaiIUMzkF6q10QHMhYGoBA&usg=AFQjCNFWupmka2OMe5H8m5OAOylePvbR0A&sig2=V_QJ-z9wLEX--zlVncOK2Q) to determine your motherboard manufacturer and model number, then use that information to go onto their website to find your motherboard's number of sata and IDE ports.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this possible in windows 7, but in windows 8 you can simply go to the system information on the control panel, and then go where indicated on the picture.

[image]

Then google the model number to find out the drive type.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes you can look at the motherboard and find the hard drive and if there is extra space around it that looks like a hard drive would go there chances are that it will take that other hard drive. I know this works with desktops but I am not sure abut laptops.